# How to print the update query which is going to execute in laravel 5.1

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

This is my code

```
$id = "'".str_replace(",","','",$id)."'";   //'7','8','9'
DB::update("UPDATE `category` 
            SET status = if(status = 'active', 'inactive', 'active') 
            WHERE cid in (?)", [$id]);
```

I need to print this update query in laravel5.1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use Laravel method `DB::enableQuerylog()` & `DB::getQuerylog()` like as

```
DB::enableQuerylog();
$id = "'".str_replace(",","','",$id)."'";   //'7','8','9'
DB::update("UPDATE `category` SET status = if(status = 'active', 'inactive', 'active') WHERE cid in (?)", [$id]);
dd(DB::getQuerylog());
```

Comment: thanks for the reply bro, 
I need to update the status of records. The above which i wrote is not working. So can you suggest me another update method to execute the above code.

Comment: I want to print query before its execution. Is it possible please let me know

Comment: Actually you can use something like as `DB::table('test')->select('*')->toSql()` @manojyadav